# What is actually mean't by the big-O graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There is a lot of Explanation about big-0, But i'm really confused on this part.

Acoording to the definition of Big-O in this function

```
f (n) ≤ c ·g(n), for n ≥ n0

“ f (n) is big-Oh of g(n).”
```

But A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function.

so for e.g here `34` is a upper bound for the set `{ 5, 10, 34 }`

[image]

So if in this graph how f(n) is O(g(n)) because if i get the upper bound of g(n) function it's value would be different than what is mentioned here for n>=n0 ..

Comment: Indeed, it is an upper bound, that's the purpose. Similarly, a lower bound is denoted big-Omega.

Comment: Beyond n0, f(n) will not grow faster than g(n). f(n)'s rate of growth as a function of n is at most g(n).

Comment: @Drakes So we are trying to mean that the worst case at which f(n) will grow can reach at max the growth rate of g(n) right ?

Comment: Yes. The worst case rate of growth of f(n) will be at most g(n) since f(n) is Big-O of g(n). This is all about knowing just how big/slow f(n) can become. For example, if f(n) = n^2, and g(n) is n^3, then trivially f(n) is Big-O of g(n) since n^2 will never grow faster than n^3.

Comment: @Drakes A big Thank you for explaining it so simply :) .. Can you just tell me the importance of 'c' here in same simple word as you explained the above. if possible ?

Comment: "c" is used for mathematical proofs - it's just a linear scaling variable. It's not important when we say "f(n) is Big-O of g(n)", just when we prove it once. No one ever asks, "Oh yeah? What's your c?" AND, we can make any c we like to show f(n) ≤ c ·g(n), for n ≥ n0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond n0, f(n) will not grow faster than g(n). f(n)'s rate of growth as a function of n is at most g(n).

g(n)'s rate of growth is said to be an upper-bound of f(n)'s rate of growth of f(n) is Big-O of g(n).

The worst case rate of growth of f(n) will be at most g(n) since f(n) is Big-O of g(n).

This is all about knowing just how big f(n) can grow relative to another known function.

For example, if f(n) = n^2, and g(n) is n^3, then trivially f(n) is Big-O of g(n) since n^2 will never grow faster than n^3.

"c" is used for mathematical proofs - it's just a linear scaling variable. We can't just go around and claim something is Big-O of something else. If we choose n0 and c for a given g(n), and this equation holds

> f(n) ≤ c ·g(n), for n ≥ n0

then we can show that truly f(n) is Big-O of g(n).

**Example:**

> f(n) = n^2;
>   g(n) = n^3;

We can choose n0 = 1, and c = 1 such that

> f(n) ≤ 1 ·g(n), for n ≥ 1

which becomes

> n^2 ≤ 1 ·n^3, for n ≥ 1

which always holds, thus f(n) is proven to be Big-O of g(n).

Proofs can get more complicated, for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879301/proving-big-oh-notation), but this is the gist of it.